# Use of 'Ort' for the food left uneaten on my plate

Tags: meaning

**Ort** means "a scrap or remainder of food from a meal":

> a morsel left at a meal [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ort)

Where **meal** means **any of the regular occasions in a day when a reasonably large amount of food is eaten.** as per a dictionary. This is what is causing me confusion as what I want to convey is not about the whole meal, I just want to write a sentence which talks only about the uneaten food on my plate.

So my question is - Can I use 'ort' for the food which was left uneaten on my plate?

Comment: What makes you think anybody ever uses this? Who do you expect will know this word?

Comment: Are you trying to translate a word from another language, or are you trying to repopularize an archaic word, or did you just find that in a (very comprehensive) dictionary and want to clarify the ancient usage. Also, your confusion is unclear; I tend to have my entire meal on one place so the 'whole meal'  is all the food on my plate so I don't see a distinction here. Are you talking about other people's plates too or a multi-course meal?

Comment: The answer by @KarlG has cleared my confusion. "We confine it to edible fragments left on the plate at meal times: when a child is supplied too abundantly, it is commonly said, "Come, clear up your plate; who, do you think, will like to eat up your orts?"                                                              
 Thanks

Comment: @tchrist  I was thinking of using it. And I usually use the words that fit the bill irrespective of the fact whether people are using it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [*Julius Caesar* IV.1](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/julius_caesar/julius_caesar.4.1.html), Antony describes Lepidus to Octavius as

> A barren-spirited fellow; one that feeds
>   On abjects, orts and imitations,
>   Which, out of use and staled by other men,
>   Begin his fashion: do not talk of him,
>   But as a property.

Lepidus' lack of independent thought and originality  feeds on *orts*, the stale intellectual leftovers of others. Shakespeare's audience easily understood the word as the still edible leftovers after a meal — what in the US would go in a *doggy bag* after a restaurant meal, even if one were planning to whip them into an omelette the next morning. Poor Lepidus had a doggy bag mind.

Moderns, of course, were not the first to hit upon the idea of feeding food scraps to animals:

> Hogs, you assert, are greedy. Yes they *swill*,
>   And, with raw meats and roots, their paunches fill.
>   Acorns they craunch, and orts, unwashed, go down
>   As glibly as the dainties of the town.  [— Robert Patterson, Recluse, *The Art of Domestick Happiness*, 1817.](https://books.google.de/books?id=rfkSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA81&dq=%22and+orts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif6uGZ6cPZAhVQI1AKHe56BeIQ6AEIWjAJ)

Or this helpful advice on raising carp:

> …chippings of bread, or *orts* of a table, steeped in tap-droppings of strong beer, or ale, are excellent food for carps. [— Abraham Rees, *Clyclopædia, or Universal Dictionary of Arts, Sciences, and Literature,* 1819.](https://books.google.de/books?id=K3cxF5vRqX4C&pg=PP553&dq=%22and+orts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIpIHJ7cPZAhXS_KQKHeU5DYo4ChDoAQgnMAE#v=onepage&q=%22and%20orts%22&f=false)

By mid-nineteenth century, however, the word had already taken on a rural, dialectical flavor and was likely no longer in active use in London:

> ORTS or ORTINGS. This word is never used in the singular with us, though there are examples of its being so used in Shakespeare. It is a common provincialism all over the kingdom, but it is used with greater latitude in some places than others. We confine it to edible fragments left on the plate at meal times: when a child is supplied too abundantly, it is commonly said, "Come, clear up your plate; who, do you think, will like to eat up your *orts*? ... Ray has the proverb—"Evening *orts* are good morning fodder."  [— Anne Elizabeth Baker, *A Glossary of Northamptonshire Words and Phrases*, 1854.](https://books.google.de/books?id=ofxIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA81&dq=%22and+orts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNkq6J5cPZAhWFI1AKHbqjDfMQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=%22and%20orts%22&f=false)

The otherwise moribund *orts* survives in more extended uses, to which Baker only alludes, having been afforded some protection by the expression [*scraps and orts*](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/531143349776914314/) for leftover bits and pieces of virtually anything, such as [embroidery thread](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22scraps+and+orts%22&rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&oq=%22scraps+and+orts%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.13540j0j8&hl=de&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), [knowledge](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v131/n3305/abs/131305a0.html), or the [miscellaneous works of German theologian Dietrich Bonhoeffer](https://hcommons.org/deposits/item/mla:391/) that survived his imprisonment and execution by the Nazis.

Another modern use of *orts* returns to domestic animals from which they were never very far in the first place. This time, however, animals are not feeding on leftovers from human dinner tables, but leaving their own leftovers:

> A composite sample of the hay fed and one of the [*orts*](https://books.google.de/books?id=3MJQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22and+orts%22&dq=%22and+orts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCptPBgMTZAhXEZlAKHWa_BsQQ6AEILTAC)  were made at the end of the trial period. The feces from each heifer were mixed thoroughly and sampled at the end of each twentyfour-hour period and these samples air-dried. (1919)
>
> Bins were weighed daily to determine individual daily intake. A sample of each cow's ration and [*orts*](https://books.google.de/books?id=k2lPAAAAYAAJ&q=%22and+orts%22&dq=%22and+orts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD7ZaZ88PZAhUCblAKHRnACpoQ6AEISDAI) were taken daily. (1996)
>
> A 100 kg spring balance with units of 0.25 kg was used to weigh feeds offered to each animal and [*orts*](https://books.google.de/books?id=R2hPAAAAYAAJ&q=offered+to+each+animal+and+orts.+Leftover+material+(orts)+was+collected+into+empty+grain+bags+.&dq=offered+to+each+animal+and+orts.+Leftover+material+(orts)+was+collected+into+empty+grain+bags+.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie04b5hMTZAhXFLVAKHU6ZA_MQ6AEIJDAA) Leftover material (orts) was collected into empty grain bags . Orts were crudely separated by feed type to determine how much of each feed was not consumed. (2006)

*Orts* has become a technical term in animal husbandry and nutrition science to mean the feed leftover after voluntary feeding in various trials or experiments.

These scraps and orts from the word history of *orts* suggest that modern usage is restricted to this expression and the technical, veterinarian use. Today, Shakespeare would have to use a word like *tablescraps* or *leftovers* to make his point generally understood.

Answer (score 5):

"Orts" is an archaic term for the food left over after a meal, which was formerly given to beggars or animals. As such, it *could* be used in your context, but "scraps" or "leftovers" would be more normal.

Answer (score 3):

[Ort](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ort):

The [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/ort) defines ort as ***archaic or dialectal***:

> (usually in the plural) A fragment; a scrap of leftover food; any remainder; a piece of refuse.
>
> - ‘*A waiter wheeled up a trolley of elaborately bedized scraps, orts and broken meats.’*
> - ‘*The men's job was to operate the sweepers, brushing up the vegetable waste, the paper bags, the scraps and orts of the Market like prairie harvesters.’*

Origin:

> remains of food left from a meal," mid-15c., probably cognate with early Dutch ooraete, Low German ort, from or-, privative prefix, + etan "to eat" (from PIE root *ed- "to eat"). Perhaps from an unrecorded Old English word.

(Etymonline)

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and%20orts%2Cthe%20orts&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%20orts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20orts%3B%2Cc0) shows only a few usage instances in recent decades.

Answer (score 3):

My parents (who were born and grew up in Greater Manchester at the beginning of the 20th century) often used the term "Eating up the orts" - but they used it to describe not just fragments of food left on the plate, but all food left over from a meal. Boxing Day was especially good for "eating up the orts".